# Connecting the linear regulator directly to AC line

Tags: power-supply, mains, linear-regulator, 7805

There are several out of the shelf solutions: [LR8](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LR8%20B080113.pdf) from Microchip (formaly known as Supertex product) and [NCP785](http://www.onsemi.ru.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP785-D.PDF) from ON-Semi. The last one is able to handle up to 700 volts at the input which is impressive.

Both components is very attractive to be used in my application. However, LR8 does not have enough voltage strength (I need to withstand 400 VAC = 625 VDC) and NCP785 is not easy to buy in my country (Russia).

One of the solutions is to put an external transistor like this:

[image]

However I think that it should be possible to add an external transistor to linear regulator (LP2981 in my case) without additional components (zener, resistors...) - this would be perfect as I need to reduce PCB size.

From my early engineering career I remember that the external transistor can be used to increase the current of the regulator, something like this:

[image]

Is it possible to do same thing to input voltage?

Comment: If R1 is really 1ohm I expect your regulator to explode quite fast.

Comment: @VladimirCravero this is not my schematic. Just took one from Internet. Actually I don;t really tried to understand how it should work.

Comment: How much current does your regulator need to supply to the load?

Comment: @Andyaka just several hundred micro Amps. MOSFET in my schematic heating for just 10-15 degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you need to rectify the incomming phase (diode + capacitor). Feeding from an alternating source is not possible.

The basic model for increasing the current of a regulator should be a little different. Here the corresponding image with the principle.

[image]

Realizing regulator with high voltage input is diffent but also feasable.
I did not find a regulator but you can build one yourself as shown in the schematic.
Ofcourse you can modify the parts etc. according to your needs and parts available.

[image]

Comment: So your approach is to skip the regulator at all. This is quite interesting! I will go deep into your schematic!

Comment: you can also use a normal regulator, if it employs an N device. You power the regulator via zener + resistor, and use an external pass device. Keep in mind that the pass transistor dissipates a lot. You have approximately 250V across it, if you only need 100mA that's 25W and it is a lot. A dcdc is probably the way to go unless you need currents in the order of 1mA.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to withstand 400 VAC = 625 VDC

A common method is to use a voltage dropping capacitor feeding a zener diode. If you have an AC input then you will be using some form of rectifier and the zener can be placed after the rectifier. For a 1 mA load, it's probably advisable to feed 2 mA into the zener and from this you can calculate the value of the capacitor that drops the voltage. This is the general idea: -

[image]

So, you get regulation (as good as a zener can provide) and very little heat produced. I estimate that C1 could have a reactance as high as 200 kohms and at 50 Hz, this means about 15 nF. R1 won't need to be a 5 watt type because your current consumption is so low (< 1mA).

PLEASE BE AWARE THAT ANY METHOD OF DERIVING A DC POWER SUPPLY FROM THE AC MAINS WITHOUT USING AN ISOLATION TRANSFORMER IS DANGEROUS.

Comment: Andy, is it still possible to measure AC voltage? One of the reason to use those resistive voltage drop (I'm currently on) is to have a possibility to measure rectified AC voltage by means of a simple resistor devider. I tried several approaches in LTSpice to combine capacitor based power supply and ADC with two resistors: no result :(

Comment: Using a half wave version you keep neutral as common for power and signal and this makes it possible but you'll have to show your circuits if you want me to comment on them.

Comment: https://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/54522/855366.8e/0_c559a_5f5ee9dc_orig.png my comments: parts on the bottom right and center left is another story, BSS126 is a current protection (another story as well). The AC measuring going through R17,18 (center top), than filtered at R3,C1 and R8,C2 (bottom left).